# passport-facebook login does not persist

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using the standard example from [here](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example/blob/master/server.js) which contains:

```
app.get('/login/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/login/facebook/return', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {     //req.user is populated
    res.redirect('/');
  });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.jade', { user: req.user });   //req.user is undefined
});
```

The login appears to work fine.  In `/login/facebook/return` I could see `req.user` and its details.  But after getting redirected to `/`, `req.user` becomes `undefined`.

Is there anything else I must add to make it work?

Comment: make sure you have `app.use(passport.initialize());` and `app.use(passport.session());` before your router.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had re-arranged the sample code had `express-session` *after* `passport.initialize()`.  By moving `express-session` before `passport.initialize()` solved the problem.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve it. I posted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Passportjs Documentations](http://passportjs.org/docs), `passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()` (for persistent logins) middlewares should be added to the `app` after `express-session`.

From the docs:

> Note that enabling session support is entirely optional, though it is recommended for most applications. If enabled, be sure to use `express.session()` before `passport.session()` to ensure that the login session is restored in the correct order.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue even though my order of `app.use(...)` is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69697669/express-login-session-only-lasts-one-page-view